# How can i find chef server version after upgrading the server?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have upgraded chef server from 11 to 12 opensource, Now i want to know how i can find chef server version if it is running old 11 or new 12. I tried "chef-server-ctl version" but didn't help me. Please help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

In your chef installation directory, you should be able to find a "version-manifest.txt" which will tell you the version.

I believe by default in Ubuntu it is located in: `/opt/chef-server/version-manifest.txt`

Comment: /opt/chef-server is the path for the open source chef-server 11, chef-server 12 is under /opt/opscode. And that doesn't tell you which server is really running.

Comment: Either way, the first line of the file gives you the version number, does it not?  If you try `head -n 1 /opt/opscode/version-manifest.txt` you should receive something similar to `chef-server 12.0.0`

Comment: Yes, but during a migration, until you asked chef12 to clean up chef 11 both path are there. After running `chef-server-ctl cleanup` that would be less a problem.